# Error in pupilFrame = cv2.equalizeHist(frame[y+(h*0.25):(y+h), x:(x+w)])

Tags: histogram-equalization

Hello i have this error in complation can any one helpe me please

##ERROR##

raceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\ASUS\Desktop\PFE Master Eye Tracker 2021\PFE_Eye_Tracker_code\opencv-eye-tracking-master\eye_control.py", line 47, in 
pupilFrame = cv2.equalizeHist(frame[y+(h*0.25):(y+h), x:(x+w)])
TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an **index** method

Process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409)

---

##CODE##
This my code

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import time

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0) #initialize video capture
left_counter=0  #counter for left movement
right_counter=0 #counter for right movement
    
th_value=5   #changeable threshold value 

def thresholding( value ):  # function to threshold and give either left or right
    global left_counter
    global right_counter
    
    if (value<=54):   #check the parameter is less than equal or greater than range to 
        left_counter=left_counter+1     #increment left counter 

        if (left_counter>th_value):  #if left counter is greater than threshold value 
            print ('RIGHT')  #the eye is left
            left_counter=0   #reset the counter

    elif(value>=54):  # same procedure for right eye
        right_counter=right_counter+1

        if(right_counter>th_value):
            print ('LEFT')
            right_counter=0
while 1:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    cv2.line(frame, (320,0), (320,480), (0,200,0), 2)
    cv2.line(frame, (0,200), (640,200), (0,200,0), 2)
    if ret==True:
        col=frame
        
        frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
        pupilFrame=frame
        clahe=frame
        blur=frame
        edges=frame
        eyes = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_eye.xml')
        detected = eyes.detectMultiScale(frame, 1.3, 5)
        for (x,y,w,h) in detected: #similar to face detection
            cv2.rectangle(frame, (x,y), ((x+w),(y+h)), (0,0,255),1)  #draw rectangle around eyes
            cv2.line(frame, (x,y), ((x+w,y+h)), (0,0,255),1)   #draw cross
            cv2.line(frame, (x+w,y), ((x,y+h)), (0,0,255),1)
            # using histogram equalization of better image.
            pupilFrame = cv2.equalizeHist(frame[y+(h*.25):(y+h), x:(x+w)])
            cl1 = cv2.createCLAHE(clipLimit=2.0, tileGridSize=(8,8)) #set grid size
            clahe = cl1.apply(pupilFrame)  #clahe
            blur = cv2.medianBlur(clahe, 7)  #median blur
            circles = cv2.HoughCircles(blur ,cv2.cv.CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT,1,20,param1=50,param2=30,minRadius=7,maxRadius=21) #houghcircles
            if circles is not None: #if atleast 1 is detected
                circles = np.round(circles[0, :]).astype("int") #change float to integer
                print ('integer',circles)
                for (x,y,r) in circles:
                    cv2.circle(pupilFrame, (x, y), r, (0, 255, 255), 2)
                    cv2.rectangle(pupilFrame, (x - 5, y - 5), (x + 5, y + 5), (0, 128, 255), -1)
                    #set thresholds
                    thresholding(x)
                    

                

        #frame = cv2.medianBlur(frame,5)
        cv2.imshow('image',pupilFrame)
        cv2.imshow('clahe', clahe)
        cv2.imshow('blur', blur)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
             break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Change * 0.25 to //4

like this:
from

```
pupilFrame = cv2.equalizeHist(frame[y+(h*.25):(y+h), x:(x+w)])
```

to

```
pupilFrame = cv2.equalizeHist(frame[y+(h//4):(y+h), x:(x+w)])
```